# Return all unique values from column, and sort them alphabetically

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So I've so far created a formula that returns all unique values from a column. In this case, the B column is the the list of values, and the D column is populated with a formula, returning all unique values from column B.

The formula is:

```
=INDEX(Table1[System], MATCH(0, COUNTIF($D$2:D2, Table1[System]), 0))
```

This is entered into cell D3 and dragged all the way down.

I'm just wondering if there's a way to amend this so that it returns all the values in alphabetical order? (without just reordering column B)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With <kbd>ExcelO365</kbd> you can use `SORT()` function with `UNIQUE()` in this way. For other version it will complex to sort.

```
=SORT(UNIQUE(A2:A11))
```

[image]

Comment: The complex non-365 variant: `=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$11, MATCH(SMALL(IF(COUNTIF($C$1:C1,$A$2:$A$11)=0,COUNTIF($A$2:$A$11,"<"&$A$2:$A$11),""),1),COUNTIF($A$2:$A$11,"<"&$A$2:$A$11),0)),"")`

Comment: Hi. Thanks guys. I believe it's 365 I'm using. However I'm not entirely sure how this works - as this workbook I'm putting together will be shared around, if someone opens the workbook in an older version of Excel, will the formula using `SORT` break? If so, would it be safer to use the version from @JvdV ?

Comment: @JvdV I think it's worth mentioning that it's an array formula and add it as a answer.

Comment: @AaronWright If anyone opens this with an older excel, then the JvdV option will be the only one that will work.

Comment: Harun24HR can feel free to include it in the answer to keep everything in one place @basic =)

Comment: Thanks Guys. @basic I implemented the formula without adding it as an array formula, and it seems to work fine. Are you sure it's an array formula?

Comment: @AaronWright yes, in pre O365 versions it must be entered as an array formula.

Comment: For O365 any array formula no need to enter as array. Its default behavior is as array  even for some non array formula. Non O365 excel need to enter CSE entry for some array formulas.

Comment: @JvdV I will add this to my post. Now I writing from mobile phone.